# Locations and types of discontinuities of the function

Tags: calculus

Classify the locations and types of discontinuities of the function f(x) = e^x for x less than 0, and x^2 for x greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more  likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

For $g(x) = e^x$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ is differentiable and therefore continuous.  For $h(x) = x^2$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$, $h(x)$ is differentiable and therefore continuous.  Since
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x), & x < 0 \\
h(x), & x \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
we only have to check zero to see if $f(x)$ is continuous there. But
$$
\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} x^2 = 0
$$
while 
$$
\lim_{x \uparrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \uparrow 0} e^x = 1 ,
$$
so there is a jump discontinuity at zero. (A function $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff for all sequences $x_n \rightarrow x_0$, $\lim_{x_n \rightarrow x_0} f(x_n) = f(x_0)$, which fails here.)